# Reference to a classical characterization of the idempotents of a ring in terms of the right (or left) annihilator

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request

Let $R$ be a (commutative or non-commutative) unital ring and denote by $r_R(\cdot)$ the right annihilator of an element. It is routine to check that, for a given $e \in R$, the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $e$ is idempotent (i.e., $e^2 = e$).
2. $R = r_R(e) \oplus r_R(1-e)$.
3. $eR = r_R(1 - e)$.

Do you happen to know of any explicit reference to this result (or to the "left-right dual" of this result) in an algebra book (e.g., among the exercises)?

Comment: Never seen it put that way. Almost every algebra book contains the combination of 2 and 3 that says $R=eR\oplus (1-e)R$ though.

Comment: Sure. But I really need the version in the OP, which, as simple as it is, implies at once the more standard version mentioned in your comment.

Comment: I understand. I'm just saying I don't recall seeing it. I've read a lot of books on ring and module theory.